# What is the brute force preventable measures does Windows 10 RDP (remote desktop) have?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, remote-desktop

I am setting up a Windows 10 remote desktop at home and was wondering what stops hackers from brute forcing my Windows 10 desktop via remote desktop? Do they get IP banned if they retry a certain amount of times?

Comment: Outsiders have to get into your computer first, so secure the computer and the network the computer hooks into

Comment: The default behavior unless you change is to lock a user account after too many unsuccessful attempts to access the account

Comment: @Ramhound so by default win10 locks the computer or just the user after how many attempts?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ - What is not clear about my comment? I specifically indicated that the user account would be locked.